# Use "master" gmail account to write to Google firebase instead of individual users?

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an Android application using Google's Firebase for the backend. I have been running through some tutorials, and they make the user sign in with their Gmail before using the app in order to read and write from the database (correct me if I'm wrong). I don't want this to be the case for the purpose of privacy and not allowing users to read and write data, so how would I not make the users authenticate with their Gmail, and instead for all reads and writes, use a general gmail specific to the app?

If I don't manually add each gmail account to the firebase console directly as either an editor or owner, then users cannot log into the app. I have been following Google's firebase tutorials found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like [Firebase anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).  Users can use an anonymous account to read and write as if they are fully authenticated, without having to go through any login process.  Then, if you want, you can later give them the option to link that account to a fully identified authenticated account from an authentication provider, such as Google.

Note that anonymous accounts don't survive application uninstall, and they can't be used by the same person across different devices.  If you want the user to be able to log in and out and retain use of the data your store on their behalf, you need to use an authentication provider to verify that the person is who they say they are.

Comment: I may have explained that wrong. The anonymous authentication is not my primary focus. I want an account that is built into the application which will make all of the database queries/writes, independent of the users gmails. Is that possible?

Comment: You could maybe do that with an email/password account, but it would not be secure, as you'd have to bake the password into the app.  Or figure out some other way to obtain it securely.   You'd also have to manage switching between the accounts, since the SDK only allows one account logged in at a time.  This really isn't a use case that's supported.